# Indexing array column in for loop: “too many indices for array”

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to index one column in an array for a for loop, and then index a different column in that same array for a for loop nested under the previous one. I keep getting the error 'IndexError: too many indices for array' and I'm not sure how to solve it.

I first made two data sets (which were stored in separate arrays) into lists so I could add them together without actually adding the values, then I made a 2D array with those two datasets combined (probably not the best way to do it but whatever).

I'm trying to find information the relies on info from both of those datasets, so I think I need them to be in the same array. Here is my code below:

```
#combining the datasets into a 2D array
bmi_all.tolist()
age.tolist()
list_age_bmi = age+bmi_all


#executing the for loop
adults = []
overweight = []

for j in list_age_bmi[:,0]:
    if j >= 18.0:
        for i in list_age_bmi[:,1]:
            if i >= 25.0:
                overweight.append(j)
        
print("Of the", len(adults), "adults in this dataset,", len(overweight), "are overweight.")
```

Comment: There's a couple of things here where you appear to have "just tried something" but don't quite know what's happening. `list_age_bmi = age+bmi_all` takes the two lists and just turns them into one list, with the elements of one all after the other - probably not what you want, given the "2D array" comment. You then loop over that whole list (ages first, then bmi) and only if you find an age or bmi over 18.0, do you loop over that whole list again and for each age or bmi over 25, you append that first age or bmi (`j`) to an `overweight` list. You could look at `zip()`, that should help.

Comment: Okay thanks! I just tried the zip() function and that seems to have worked.